# Python BeautifulSoup check output

Tags: python, urllib, webrequest, beautifulsoup

I try to check what a website prints out.
So imagine:

```
page = requests.get("testsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
if soup in ["my", "wished", "output"]:
    print "It's there!"
else:
    print "It's not there!"
```

So I want to check if the website is containing the text "my", "wished" or "output". How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you checking? Your example doesn't makes sense.

Comment: I know. Because of that, Im here. I want to check if the website is containing the text "my", "wished" or "output"

Answer (score 2):

```
page = requests.get("testsite.com")
test = ["my", "wished", "output"]
if any(t in page.text for t in test):
    print("It's there!")
else:
    print("It's not there!")
```

`soup` is BeautifulSoup object, if you want to check if text in string, you should use `string object` like `page.text`

> `any(iterable)` Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return False.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function and to find strings in `page`. If there is neither of the wanted string in the `page`, returned list will contain only `-1` (ie. `[-1, -1, -1]`). So, just check if there is number that is bigger than `-1`.

```
page = requests.get("testsite.com")
page = page.text
wanted = ["my", "wished", "output"]
if max(map(page.find, wanted)) > -1:
    print "It's there!"
else:
    print "It's not there!"
```